# error while redirecting one page to other in django

Tags: python, django

Basically, from and to both page have parameters so how can I redirect to page with parameters?

**html page:**

```
{% for vr in adduser.adduser.all %}
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'edituser' id=vr.id bid=adduser.id %}">
{% csrf_token %}
 <label for="FirstName">First Name<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="Type FirstName here...." value="{{vr.f_name}}">
 <label for="LastName">Last Name<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Type LastName here...." value="{{vr.l_name}}">
{% endfor %}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('edituser/<uid>/<bid>', views.edituser, name="edituser"),
```

**views.py**

```
def edituser(request, uid, bid):
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.POST.get('firstname') and request.POST.get('lastname'):
        saverecord = AddContact()
        saverecord.id = uid
        saverecord.f_name = request.POST.get('firstname')
        saverecord.l_name = request.POST.get('lastname')
        saverecord.save()
        viewRecords = AddContact.objects.filter(subscribe='subscribe')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('adduser',bid))
    else:
        viewRecords = AddContact.objects.filter(subscribe='subscribe')
        messages.error(request, "Error During Editing of Contact")
        return redirect(request, 'broadcastlist.html')
else:
    viewRecords = AddContact.objects.filter(subscribe='subscribe')
    messages.error(request, "Error During Editing of Contact")
    return redirect(request, 'broadcastlist.html')
```

To clarify more uid is userid which is for edit the user and bid is broadcast id which is to redirect to the broadcast list.

Comment: You should search your question before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47731160/django-redirect-to-view-with-parameters

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to another page in Django with parameters use this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(viewname='the view to which it should redirect', args=(parameters to be passed)))
```

Comment: after applying your method, i've come to one conclusion that in url it got the bid but it is not removing uid. Hence the both id is coming like that:-https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yUjfq0kX1jrVJ4zszLLhmlvGFraLguBN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes you should modify the URL path route for redirection url like this route='edituser/<sint:id>/<int:id2>/ and then modify your views.py to accept the parameters like that  def sample_view(request,id,id1):

Comment: if i put id, id2 in url and id,id1 in function than it will give an error like : edituser() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id2'

Comment: yes the name in url must match the parameter's name the function was expecting

Comment: but still its not working :(

Comment: how? please edit your question to add details like your new views.py, urls.py and error

Answer (score 0):

Use `redirect`, it's easier than invoking `reverse` and `HttpResponseRedirect` directly. [(Doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
...
    return redirect( 'myapp:url_name', urlparam=value, ...)
```

which is the same as

```
    return HttpResponseRedirect( 
         reverse( 'myapp:url_name',
         kwargs={ 'urlparam': value, ... } 
    )
```